# How to get the value of a variable which is partially created from a string?

Tags: php, variables

```
$prefix = 'some';
$name_of_variable = $prefix.'_var';
```

So I have a variable named `$some_var`.

How can I check the value of it?

`if($name_of_variable) ...`

will return the value of `$name_of_variable` instead of the value of `$name_of_variable`.

Comment: This is called variable variables and is regarded bad practice. Consider whether you can use an array instead

Comment: if you care to tell us context of such an unusual variable usage, we well be able to tell you the best an proper solution

Comment: well your are right, I could use a array instead. Actually I have a array, but I used extract to create variables from it, so I thought I could check the variables somehow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But you do NOT want to use them. They make for impossible-to-debug code. They're almost always a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT use a variable which is partially created from a string.
Use arrays instead.

```
$prefix = 'some';
$name_of_variable = 'var';
echo $array[$prefix][$name_of_variable];
```

Answer (score -1):

Variable variable usually used when you need to create variables from string,for example convert $_POST keys into variable with its value .

```
$allowed_var = array('name',..);
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value
{
   if( isset($allowed_var[$key] ) )
        ${$key} = $value;
}
...
```

Comment: That's 100500 times worse than ordinal variable variables, making  a hole in your site of the size of one poor Titanic had.

Comment: Just for demonstration ! , what about add array to check if the name of created variable allowed ? every technique we used must have a security layer on top of it .